# BLE: Why are Write Commands slower than Notifications?

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, throughput

In the context of BLE (Bluetooth Low Energy), Write Commands can be used to write from a Client to the Server, and Notifications to write from the Server to the Client. In my setup, the Client is a Central device (Android phone), and the Server is a Peripheral (dev board).

After performing several data throughput tests with multiple phones, I noticed that the throughput varies greatly with the phone, which is expected because a great deal of the BLE lower layers implementation is up to the manufacturer to figure out. But what caught my attention was that Write Command **always** achieve a much lower throughput that Notifications, independently from the phone. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

They should have the same throughput. Multiple write commands and notifications can be sent during one connection event. They are treated the same.

You could use an air sniffer to see if you find any problems.

How long the connection event should be open can be suggested when the connection is created and with connection parameter updates. Sadly, Android's BLE stack hard codes this to the default value, which means no recommendation. That will in practice mean you are limited to 3 or 4 packets per connection event.